# How to get diff between two hours in moment.js?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have two hours:

```
const a = "09:00";
const b = "10:00";
```

when i try using `diff` from momentjs like this:

```
moment(a).diff(b).format("HH:mm");
```

then this funciotn return me "02:00" instead of "01:00",
can someone tell me why this return me wrong result?

Comment: FYI, `moment` cant format duration

Comment: This code most likely outputs a waring about using the native Date conversion being discouraged too. You should probably use moment as it was intended for better results. Follow the instructions in the docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
const a = moment("09:00","HH:mm", true).format();

const b = moment("11:00","HH:mm", true).format();



var c = moment(b).diff(a,"minutes", true);

var d = moment().hours(0).minutes(c).format('HH:mm');


alert(d);
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```